# Spring-data-Jpa and Hibernate-entitimanager dependency conflict in gradle project

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager, gradle-dependencies

I have a gradle project. I am new to gradle and converted one of my project to gradle. My project was working then it started me giving error. Then I noticed that if I comment out my Hibernate-entitymanger dependency, then no error.

Here is my build.gradle snippet

```
apply plugin: 'application' // implicitly apply java and distribution plugin
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

ext {
     //Spring
    springFrameworkGroupId = "org.springframework"
    springFrameworkVersion = "4.2.4.RELEASE"
    springDataJpaVersion = "1.9.2.RELEASE"

    //Hibernate
    hibernateEntityManagerVersion = "5.1.0.Final"
    hibernateValidatorVersion = "5.2.3.Final"
    sqlJdbc4Version = "4.0"
    ....
}

dependencies {
    compile group: log4jGroupId, name: 'log4j-api', version: log4jVersion
    compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
    ['spring-context-support', 'spring-jdbc', 'spring-oxm', 'spring-orm', 'spring-jms', 'spring-test'].each {
        compile "$springFrameworkGroupId:$it:$springFrameworkVersion"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: springDataJpaVersion
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateEntityManagerVersion
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: sqlJdbc4Version
    ....
}
```

I am simply doing

```
try (GenericApplicationContext springRootContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootContext.class)) {    //error
        BatchImportRequestService batchImportRequestService = springRootContext.getBean(BatchImportRequestServiceImpl.class);
        batchImportRequestService.handleRequest(springRootContext, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurs in loading Spring root context: ", e);
    }
```

When I do this it gives me error that

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/basit.ahmed/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all/5.13.0/4dc8405e5e52a05197e4e91d0e46b353107bcfe0/activemq-all-5.13.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/basit.ahmed/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.5/d1e34a4525e08873703fdaad6c6284f944f8ca8f/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;)V
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:413)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:392)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:929)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
....
```

But if comment out my `hibernate-entitymaanger` dependency, then it stats working. Like

```
compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
  ['spring-context-support', 'spring-jdbc', 'spring-oxm', 'spring-orm', 'spring-jms', 'spring-test'].each {
    compile "$springFrameworkGroupId:$it:$springFrameworkVersion"
}
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: springDataJpaVersion
//compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateEntityManagerVersion
...
```

I also run dependency-tree task. Here what I got

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
...
+--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.4.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.11.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.7
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13 (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
+--- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0
```

default - Configuration for default artifacts.

```
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.11.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.7
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13 (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
+--- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0
```

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.

```
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.11.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.9.RELEASE -> 4.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.7
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.13 (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
+--- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0
```

How can I solve this issue ? Why I am getting error in case of `Hibernate-entitymanger` inclusion ?

Thanks